# Redacting information in pdf programmatically

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, saas, sensitive-data

I would like some suggestions on how I can achieve this. While there is discussion on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044591/how-do-you-programmatically-redact-pdf-files), it is six years old and I am hoping there are SaaS solutions available today or easy way to do it.

I would like to run a program on tax-returns in pdf format that would remove or redact sensitive information from the pdf file such as Name, Address, SSN, and other PII, and generate a public copy of the tax return in pdf that is safe to share with others.

The source of the pdf can be a scanner or tax software.  Is it there an easy way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: My need would suffice, if I can identify a list of all the IRS forms used in the tax returns.

Comment: This is a question better suited for software Recs, but as a side-note: there is something rather contradictory about sending sensitive-date documents to a third-party service in order to redact the senstive information.

Comment: I am providing taxcaddy at findtaxpro.com for storing sensitive info and want to share the "hygiened" PDF for estimates in the findtaxpro marketplace.  So not contradictory.   Do you mean software requisition?

Comment: *"Do you mean software requisition?"* - Software Recommendations, I presume: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - stack overflow is meant for very specific problems *using a given API/library/service*, not for *finding* one.

Comment: How do you expect the software to recognize the sensitive information? In particular scanned pages might have additional or missing margins, they might even be scanned upside-down or something similar, and they usually are scanned a bit rotated.

Comment: I just want the form name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SaaS based image storage and manipulation service called cloudinary (cloudinary.com) which has an add-on that may help to redact text, see: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/ocr_text_detection_and_extraction_addon

How are these files being presented? e.g. are the PDF files viewed on the web or via an application as images?

[i am not affiliated with cloudinary]